# firebird, insert records using query window

Tags: database, firebird

I have the database table `AllowedFields` with the following columns:

```
ID int
Name Varchar(50)
FieldRecord Decimal(7,2)
```

I am trying to insert demo records using the following query:

```
set term ^ ;
EXECUTE BLOCK AS BEGIN
INSERT INTO AllowedFields(Name, FieldRecord) VALUES ("A", 0.00);
INSERT INTO AllowedFields(Name, FieldRecord) VALUES ("E", 13.00);
END^
```

But I am getting this error message:

```
Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -206
Column unknown
A
At line 3, column 37
```

Obviously firebird sees this `A` value as a column value?

How would I change this script to insert a record. Thanks.

Comment: Try using single quotes for string literals: 'A', and 'E'.

Comment: @mbeckish :) thanks, please post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You can go ahead and give the credit to @a_horse_with_no_name. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL standard defines double quotes to denote identifiers (table names, column names, constraint names, ...). So `"A"` identifies a column named `A` and not a single character.

String literals have to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. So you need to use `'A'` to denote a string (character) literal.

Putting this together you need:

```
INSERT INTO AllowedFields(Name, FieldRecord) VALUES ('A', 0.00);
INSERT INTO AllowedFields(Name, FieldRecord) VALUES ('E', 13.00);
```

You should also be aware that the standard requires quoted names to be case-sensitive, so `"A"` is a different column than `"a"`).

And Firebird follows the standard.

Comment: There is an exception: if you are using the legacy dialect 1 instead of dialect 3, then double quotes can be used to delimit strings. However dialect 1 should be considered deprecated since Interbase 6 / Firebird 1 (2000ish)